# Re-run 'matched contacts suggestion'

Tags: contacts, htc-sense

I have a hTc Evo 3D, with hTc sense. Sense has a great little tool that matches contacts from different accounts, so that all the details for a particular person are linked. i.e. Facebook, Twitter and Phone number are stored together, under a common entry.

Does anyone know how to force this to do a re-run over all my contacts? I ask because I was in a hurry the first time it ran and only accepted a few of it's suggestions and now I want to match up the remaining contacts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact answer, but you can always manual link contacts, which is a workaround I use,

1. In Contacts, open one contact, then click the broken clip icon in the top-right corner (I am using Sensation XE).
2. In the pop up screen, choose all contacts
3. Search for the one you want to link to and click it

Then the two contact items are linked if you click Finish. You can click Cancel if you don't want them to be linked.